# iOS spritekitでノードが表示されない

Tags: ios, spritekit

すいません、初歩的なことをお伺いします。
現在、簡単なゲームを作成しようとしていましてその過程で困っています。
画像のようにプログラムを書いてみてもシュミレーターに表示されません。
エラーも出てらず、行き詰まってしまっています。
どうすれば表示されるようになるのか？それとも他に問題があるのか？
ご回答のほうをお待ちしています。

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        //        画像からスプライトを作成する
        let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "kuri_2.png")
        //        サイズプロパティでサイズを設定
        mySprite.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        //        ポジションプロパティで設定
        // 画像の描画場所を指定.
        mySprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        addChild(mySprite)

//        回転の動きをいれる
        let action1 = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(90 * M_PI / 180), duration: 1)
//        移動する動きを加える
        let action2 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: 400,y: 400), duration: 1)
//        二つの動きを同時に処理
        let actionx = SKAction.group([action1,action2])
//        動きをつけます
        mySprite.runAction(actionx)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
           }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ご提示のコードを、そのままXcodeのプロジェクトにコピー＆ペーストしてビルドしたら、ノード`mySprite`が表示され、アニメーションもしました。なので、ご提示のコード以外の部分に不備な点があるのだと考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

Zpositionなどはどうなですか？あと重力が働いていて、表示と同時に落下してしまっていて見える前から画面から消えているという可能性、初歩的な指摘ですか、奇跡的にお役に立てればと出しゃばりました。